# Exception on a python code that give an HTML page

Tags: python

For a school project i have to make a translator with python. The task is to use the dictionary function to make the translation.

The translator contain only 20 words, written in different languages on a txt files. The word that have to be translated, the initial and the final language come from an html form. And also the result must be printed on an html page. My program works, but I can't manage the exceptions.

The program must print a specific message error when the field of word is left empty in the form or when a word that is not in the txt file is used.

I have tried with Try/except but html give me just a white page. Can someone explain me why this doesn't work? And also, this would only solve the problem when the field is empty, how can I get a proper error message when I type a word that is not in the txt files?

```
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
form= cgi.FieldStorage()
try:
    language1 = str(form["startlanguage"].value)
    language2 = str(form["finallanguage"].value)
    word = str(form["word"].value)
    translator= dict ()
    if language1=="ita" and language2=="eng":
            itaeng= open("itafraeng.txt", "r")
            for row in itaeng:
                    wordita, wordfra, wordeng = riga.split()
                    translator[wordita]=wordeng
            itaeng.close()        
    print '''<html>
             <body>
             <p>%s = %s </p>
             </body>
             <html>''' % (word, translator[word])

except KeyError:
   print ' Error '
```

EDIT: Someone told me that with my old code i don't realy use the dictionary function so i tried to change it but now it doesn't work anymore. Can someone explain why?

Comment: replace `except KeyError:
    ' Error '`with `except Exception as e:  print(e)` and post the error message.

Comment: seems you have always error in code so it always execute `except KeyError:` but you don't use `print` to display anything.

Comment: you can also use `print` to display all values in variables - it will help you find problem.

Comment: @furas i totaly forgot the print in the except KeyError. Now when the text box in the form is empty it display the right error message so thank you! But how can i set a proper error message when i try to translate a word that is not in the txt files?

Comment: you can set `found = False` at start. And later use `if word==wordita: found = True` so at the end you can use `if not found: print "Not found"`

Comment: @furas Thank you again for the answer! A friends pointed out to me that with my old code i don't realy use the dictionary function so i tried to make a new one but this doesn't work. Can you help me again?

Comment: as for me you don't need dictionary. You have to find word in file - and you don't have to keep all other words in dictionary.

Comment: BTW: your code can't work because you use variable `riga` which doesn't exists.

Comment: version without dictionary: http://pastebin.com/6S8U0p99

Comment: version with dictionary: http://pastebin.com/Xy56nS8K